# Upgrading Corda Flow causes error on next run: TransactionVerificationException$ContractConstraintRejection

Tags: corda

As mentioned in the docs on [performing flow upgrades](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#performing-flow-upgrades), all you need to do is basically shut down the node, replace JAR, and start the node back up. When I do this, when my upgraded flow is run the next time, I get the following error:

```
net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractConstraintRejection: Contract constraints failed for com.company.project.contract.MyContract, transaction: ABCDEFG
```

And the flow does not complete as a result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi can you confirm if you are using single jar for contract and flows or two different jars. If you are using two different jars this error should not occur. If you are using a single jar follow the steps as mentioned by Sateinpong below. Please advise is your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As my experience it seem like Corda flow upgrade not update network parameter (state still belong to old hash, old contract). Then when replace with new contract it will be contract constraint.
So I think you have 3 way to manage this

1. For local network bootstrap, update network parameter before doing flow upgrade (I use network-bootstrap.jar for copy new contract to cordapp folder, then it will append new contract hash immediately)
2. For Corda network, you must contact network operator for update new hash.
3. Use SignatureConstraint of Corda4 (they claim that it's upgrade easier but I didn't try yet)

Hope this help